# Django query returning empty data after order_by()

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm making queries with `filter()` and `exclude()` depending on the search criteria of the user. I'm also sorting the query according to the search if specified. Everything works fine except when the user use the `exclude()` function and try to sort in a `related_field`. It works with `filter()`, though.

I'm using Django 1.10 and Postgresql

The model simplified is the following:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=175)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        db_table = 'project'

class Summary(models.Model):
    mykey = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    external_order_id = models.ManyToManyField('Project', blank=True)
```

The query

```
project = InventoryProject.objects.get(name='')
# with exclude
# this one returns [], but if I do .count() it returns the correct number of rows
queryset.annotate(num_projects=Count('external_order_id')).exclude(external_order_id=project, num_projects=1).order_by('external_order_id')

# with filter
# this one works like a charm
queryset = queryset.annotate(num_projects=Count('external_order_id')).filter(external_order_id=project, num_projects=1)
```

I checked the `.query` attribute before and after the order by and they seem very different

```
// before (it shows all the data)
SELECT "summary"."mykey", 
    COUNT("summary_external_order_id"."project_id") AS "num_projects" 
    FROM "summary" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "summary_external_order_id" ON ("summary"."mykey" = "summary_external_order_id"."summary_id") 
    GROUP BY "summary"."mykey" 
    HAVING NOT ("summary"."mykey" IN 
        (SELECT U1."summary_id" AS Col1 FROM "summary_external_order_id" U1 WHERE U1."project_id" = 1) AND COUNT("summary_external_order_id"."project_id") = 1)

// after (doesn't show any data)
SELECT "summary"."mykey", 
    COUNT("summary_external_order_id"."project_id") AS "num_projects" 
    FROM "summary" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "summary_external_order_id" ON ("summary"."mykey" = "summary_external_order_id"."summary_id") 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "project" ON ("summary_external_order_id"."project_id" = "project"."id") 
    GROUP BY "summary"."mykey", "project"."name" 
    HAVING NOT ("summary"."mykey" IN 
        (SELECT U1."summary_id" AS Col1 FROM "summary_external_order_id" U1 WHERE U1."project_id" = 1) AND COUNT("summary_external_order_id"."project_id") = 1) 
    ORDER BY "project"."name" ASC
```

I'm not sure why django automatically group by 'mykey'. Also, if I remove "project"."name" from the group by it works...

**EDIT**:
As requested here is the data for the "Project" table where ID is 1

```
id [pk] - integer | name - character varying(175)
1                 |
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that you are trying to order by a ManyToMany relation. I don't see how that would work...

Comment: Right, I agree with that point. It seems wrong to order by a M2M. But the thing is why does it return data when I use `filter()` and not when I use `exclude()`?

Comment: Well it has to group by `mykey` to process your `Count` aggregation. Is `name` blank or null for project 1? Can you show us the table data for project 1?

Comment: yes, `name` is blank for the project which the id is 1